# How to pull data on flutter in-app purchases

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to add in-app purchase for my application that does not have user login or registration, and when the user makes a one-time purchase, the ads will be removed and some features will be opened. but if the user deletes and installs the app, will they be able to pull the purchase history from the play store? How is the process going? I do not have an online database, only local in the application.

https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase I think we will install the package here, but do I need to try another method, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will be able to restore previous non-consumable purchases after a re-install or install on a new device. You do not need your own app login, the user already has a relationship to the App Store / Google Play, and you do not necessarily need your own database, as the stores will have the purchase records for the user.

It's not too difficult if you have already implemented purchases. You will need to provide a 'Restore Purchases' UI option somewhere in your app and have that call **InAppPurchase.instance.restorePurchases()**

If you have implemented the queue listener as documented on the [plugin page](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) you will receive purchaseDetails events with **status == PurchaseStatus.restored**, which you will process in much the same way as for status == PurchaseStatus.purchased

This is all reasonably well documented on the plugin page and in the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0)

Answer (score 0):

Non consumables - subsriptions can be restored. Restore does not work with consumables or one time purchases. One time purchase is the same as consumables and they must be persisted on backend and you must have mechanism for sycing with the stores, for example for Google Play you must have Pub/Sub on Android developer topic that you setup.